# How To Redirect Multiple Dynamic URL to Single Static URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to Redirect this 404 error URL to a Static URL. How this is possible. Please help..

URL http://www.takeshiyashima.com

```
/us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education  
/ja/resources?id=366:video-clip  
/ja/resources?id=364:mortgage-reset-second-big-wave 
/us/my-blog/65-investment?catid=230&id=230:wealth-cycle9 
/us/resources?catid=72&id=354:fractional-reserve-banking
/us/my-blog?catid=1&id=432:petrodollar-system-inevitable-economic-collapse-and-possibility-of-world-war-iii 
/tw/?catid=0&id=539 
/tw/?catid=0&id=519 
/ja/resources?catid=72&id=357:flaw-of-401k 
/us/my-blog/65-investment?catid=301&id=301:my-recent-real-estate-deal-and-why-i-am-investing-in-real-estate 
/tw/?catid=0&id=502
/ja/?catid=0&id=516
```

I have 561 error in google webmaster. Please help me to redirect this type of URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to, say, redirect all requests for a non-existent page to `http://example.com/404.php`, just add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php
```

However, it's often better to serve `404.php` page *without* visibly changing the URL.  This is even easier:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Note that, with the latter solution, those pages will still show up as 404 errors e.g. in Google's webmaster tools.  However, that is actually a *good* thing, since it lets you tell missing pages apart from redirects.  Users visiting those pages will still see your `404.php` page, just served under the missing page's URL, and with a 404 status code.

For more information, see [Custom Error Responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html) in the Apache documentation.

---

Ps. Note that this will *not* work if your 404 errors are generated by some application framework or script (i.e. the script is successfully executed, but deliberately returns a 404 response, e.g. because it can't find the requested resource in the database).  In that case, the solution will depend on the specific application or script.

Comment: Actually I want /us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education this URL to redirect in http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog/1-my-thought/404-my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education this URL. And All the URL i want to redirect in their similar URLs.

Comment: @graphicdesigner: Do you have a list / database of which URL should redirect to which one?

Comment: I have the list of crawl error URL but I didn't make any list for redirection URL. here is the link of the url to redirect in their similar pages https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvg3atbdw9aqvy/www-takeshiyashima-com_20140514T075551Z_CrawlErrors.csv ..

Comment: You may understand some URL i just want to remove the parameter. I give you some example below.

1> ja/resources?id=366:video-clip TO http://www.takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources  

2> a/resources?id=364:mortgage-reset-second-big-wave To http://www.takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources 

3> /us/my-blog/65-investment?catid=230&id=230:wealth-cycle9 TO http://www.takeshiyashima.com/my-blog/65-investment/230-wealth-cycle

Answer (score 0):

use **.htaccess** redirection

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]
```

Blog: [Redirect your 404 error to a Custom Page](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962936/725306) on Stack Overflow

Comment: What to do ?? copy the code to my .htaccess as you given or i have to change something. Please give me a specific code which will sure work and Google bot can crawl the page.  I have tired of trying a lot of code. I have already a 404 page but i want this URL to redirect in specific Static URL.