# How to rewrite URL based on http status code (IIS)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, redirect

I am configuring a IIS reversed proxy that rewrite the URL and redirect request to an IIS server (ServerA) that serves a web service. In the case of failure, for example, a 503 http status code returned by the web service. I would like to rewrite the URL and redirect the request to another IIS server(ServerB) that serves a mirrored copy of the web service. Is this achievable? Thanks!

Comment: Does it help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess

Comment: That doesn't let me rewrite the host and pass any data that was passed previously in the original request though.