# Redirect into my designed 404 page if URL does not exist

Tags: php

I want to create a PHP script that allows me to redirect a user into a 404 page (designed by me) to tell him that the url request by him does not exist. Currently I am working offline, so my server folder is `www/myproject/pages.php` and if a user typed `localhost/myproject/files.php` per example, I want to take him into a 404 error page.

I know I should use something like `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` but I don't know how to make the condition:

if(url does not exist in my working folder).

I've tried this script:

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

from [this link but still can't know how to add the condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)

Comment: Your link refer to a total different question (how to check if an **external** url does not exist). You have to modify .htaccess (or apache config) to redirect 404 on your site. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks that was really helpfull

Answer (score 3):

You can do routing in PHP as well. Something like https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute if you want. Any undefined routes(pages) can be pushed to a 404 page.

Alternatively use your .htaccess or nginx config to redirect pages that don't exist.

**nginx**

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

**apache**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.html
```

**htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]
```

Comment: I can't find .htacess in my wamp server folder

Comment: You can create one if it isn't there. There's a few tutorials on doing this an enabling it.

Comment: @LaraCh: How are you checking for .htaccess ? It is hidden sometimes. Like when you access it by non root user on cpanel or using any tool like winSCP. Make sure you can see the hidden files.