# Angular Url not working after removing # in new tab or after reload

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I am working in angular project. I am using angular ui routing. link is http://keraiz.com. I need to remove # from url. so I enable html5 mode by

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

The I define base href by `<base href = '/' />`
then I write rewite rules in .htassess file -

```
 RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

Now on same tab it is working fine. but If I reload link or open line in new tab it jump on 404 page. so how can I resolve this issue. I don't want to go 404 page. like if there is request of keraiz.com/about then i want to go about page

Comment: Based off this previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess) I would suggest doing something like this


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
`

Comment: I don't want to go 404 page. like if there is request of  http://keraiz.com/about then i want to go about page

Comment: i am not sure if it is the same as nginx, but with nginx, the 404 redirect to index.html will force it go to index.html and angular will lookup the path AFAIK