# Check if image exists without getting 404 error (adWords fails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

I have a site where you can search for products. 
All product images are named like `img/product/{id}.jpg.`
Some product images are missing, and if they are `image_missing.jpg` should be displayed instead.

I found this code to accomplish this:

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}

/* check if image exists */
if(UrlExists(imageURL) == true){
    /* image exists, do nothing */
}
else{
    imageURL = 'img/product/image_missing.jpg';
}
```

This works fine. If the image doesn't exists it is replaced by `image_missing.jpg`.

The problem is that i still get

> ( ! ) failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

in the console when the page is loaded.

**Even tho there is no broken images on the site, Google AdWords sees all these 404s (7 at the moment) and doesn't allow me to have the page as a landing page for my campaign.**

Is there a way to check if an image exists without getting 404s? I would very much appreciate any help i can get here.

Comment: The response has to come back as a 404 for your logic to work. There is no way around this, except to change the HTTP response code on the server side, but even then they would still be reported in AdWords. A better solution would be to actually keep track of what images do/do not exist in your server side logic instead of always attempting to load images which don't exist.

Comment: perhaps this could be amended to work in the way you wanted? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will check if the image exists in the PHP file that fetches the data in the first place. How can i mark your response as correct? (I'm new to stack :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following without making a HTTP request just to check if the image exist:

```
function UrlExists(imageUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let imageData = new Image();

    imageData.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    }

    imageData.onerror = () => {
      reject()
    }

    imageData.src = imageUrl;
  })
}
```

Use the above function as follows:

```
UrlExists(imageURL)
  .then(function(result){
    // resolve here
    // image exists, do nothing
  }, function(error) {
    // reject here
    imageURL = 'img/product/image_missing.jpg';
  });
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but your biggest concern here is that there should not be any error shown in the console even if an image don't exist right?

Comment: Exactly, if image is not present it is not critical in our use case, and it is not nice to see that error in console...