# How to not redirect to 404 page for a specific domain page

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I wanted to add a 404 page to my website but i had some problems.

I made a .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

It works fine but i don't want that to give a 404 everytime.

What i want is that the htaccess dosn't redirect you to the 404 page, for a specific domain name page.

Comment: Not sure if this gives and answer or not, but please have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess

Comment: No that is redirecting to specific page when a 404, not 404 not to a specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want that `ErrorDocument` to be defined for a specific domain then enclose the `ErrorDocument` directive in a negated `<If>` expression that checks that the requested `Host` header is not `example.com` (the domain you want to exclude).

For example (requires Apache 2.4):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com'">
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</If>
```

The `ErrorDocument` is defined for every requested host, except `example.com`. (Obviously, you'll still get a 404 response for this other domain, when requesting a non-existent resource, but `/404.html` will not be served.)

---

*Aside:*

> the htaccess dosn't redirect you to the 404 page

Probably just terminology, but there is no "redirect" (as in an external 3xx redirect) here to begin with. The error document is served with an internal subrequest. You could change the `ErrorDocument` directive so that it does trigger a "redirect", but that is rarely desirable.